# Does activating Priest of the Forgotten Gods ability trigger Korvold's last ability twice?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I use [Priest of Forgotten Gods](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPriest%20of%20Forgotten%20Gods%5d)' ability to sacrifice two creatures, does it proc [Korvold, Fae-Cursed King](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKorvold%2c%20Fae-Cursed%20King%5d)'s ability twice? My doubt stems from the fact that the sacrifice of the creatures occurs simultaneously.

I think it should proc twice since I believe to have seen [Mayhem Devil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMayhem%20Devil%5d)'s ability proccing twice under similar circumstances, but I'd appreciate some explicit reference to relevant rules if possible.

Comment: If it wouldn't be triggered, the wording would read "if/whenever one or more [things happen]".

Comment: Specifically, Korvold's ability would read "When(ever?) you sacrifice one or more permanents", triggering once for the sacrificing, instead of once per permanent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, activating Priest of the Forgotten Gods' ability and sacrificing two creatures simultaneously triggers Korvold's last ability twice.**

[Rule 603.2c](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Triggered_ability) says this:

> **603.2c** An ability triggers only once each time its trigger event occurs. However, it can trigger repeatedly if one event contains multiple occurrences.
>
> ***Example:** A permanent has an ability whose trigger condition reads, “Whenever a land is put into a graveyard from the battlefield, . . . .” If someone casts a spell that destroys all lands, the ability will trigger once for each land put into the graveyard during the spell’s resolution.*

In this case, the single event of activating Priest of the Forgotten Gods contains two occurrences of sacrificing a creature, so Korvold's ability that triggers "Whenever you sacrifice a permanent" triggers twice.

Comment: There are cases that are more complicated, however. For instance, if something triggers on scrying, then three instances of scry 1 will trigger it three times, but one instance of scry 3 will trigger it only once.

Comment: In general, the numeric parameter of a keyword ability or action does not mean "do something N times".

Comment: Is it worth mentioning "Whenever one or more..." triggers, or are they too self evident?